# VBA: Insert table from Excel to Email body - line is overwriting previous line

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA code converting my Excel file to PDF, attaching it in an email and then copying one sheet from my workbook into the email body. The sheet in my Excel contains a table and some text.
I want to insert text in the body above and below my text/table pasted from Excel, but the I only see "Best regards" in the body as the last line is overwriting the previous one and so... I'm using the GetInspector but I do something wrong.

My code is here:

```
    Sub ConvertToPDFAndEmailWithSheetContent()
    Dim PDFFileName As String
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim QuoteSheet As Worksheet
    Dim TempFileName As String
    Dim TableHTML As String

    ' Set the PDF file name and path
    PDFFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Replace(ThisWorkbook.Name, ".xlsm", ".pdf")

  ' Hide sheets without data in cell F6
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If IsEmpty(ws.Range("F6").Value) Then
            ws.Visible = xlSheetHidden
        End If
    Next ws
    

    ' Save the workbook as PDF
    ActiveWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:=PDFFileName, Quality:=xlQualityStandard

    ' Create a new Outlook application
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    ' Set the reference to the "Price Quote" sheet
    Set QuoteSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Price Quote")

    ' Copy the print area to a new temporary sheet
    QuoteSheet.UsedRange.Copy

    ' Include the content of the print area as a table in the email body
    With OutMail
        .GetInspector.WordEditor.Range.Text = "Dear recipient," & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Please find the price     quote details below:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
        
            ' Move to the end of the existing text
     .GetInspector.WordEditor.Application.Selection.MoveEnd
    
        .GetInspector.WordEditor.Range.Paste
        
         ' Move to the end again
      .GetInspector.WordEditor.Application.Selection.MoveEnd
    
        .GetInspector.WordEditor.Range.Text = "Best Regards"
        .Subject = "Price Quotation"
        .To = "recipient@example.com" ' Replace with the recipient's email address
        .Attachments.Add PDFFileName
        .Display ' You can use .Send instead of .Display to send the email automatically

    End With

    ' Clean up
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
   ' TempSheet.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Set QuoteSheet = Nothing
    Set TempSheet = Nothing
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp =` Nothing

    ' Delete the PDF file (optional)
    Kill PDFFileName
    
    UnhideAllSheets
    
End Sub
```

I tried different formats of my pasting to the body.

Comment: Try with paragraphs `With .GetInspector.WordEditor.Paragraphs : .Add.Range.Text = "text" : .Add.Range.Paste : .Add.Range.Text = "more text" : End With`

Comment: @CDP1802 It seems to overwrite the initial "text".

Answer (score 1):

Try the following...

```
' Include the content of the print area as a table in the email body
With OutMail
    .Display
    .To = "recipient@example.com" ' Replace with the recipient's email address
    .Subject = "Price Quotation"
    .Attachments.Add PDFFileName
    With .GetInspector.WordEditor
        .Application.Selection.TypeText "Dear recipient," & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Please find the price quote details below:"
        ' Move to the end of the existing text
        .Application.Selection.EndKey Unit:=6 'wdStory
        .Application.Selection.TypeParagraph
        .Application.Selection.TypeParagraph
        .Application.Selection.Paste
        ' Move to the end again
        .Application.Selection.EndKey Unit:=6 'wdStory
        .Application.Selection.TypeParagraph
        .Application.Selection.TypeParagraph
        .Application.Selection.TypeText "Best Regards"
    End With
End With
```

**EDIT**

[Option 1]

```
Dim signature As String

' Include the content of the print area as a table in the email body
With OutMail
    .Display
    .To = "recipient@example.com" ' Replace with the recipient's email address
    .Subject = "Price Quotation"
    signature = .htmlbody
    .htmlbody = ""
    With .GetInspector.WordEditor
        .Application.Selection.TypeText "Dear recipient," & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Please find the price quote details below:"
        ' Move to the end of the existing text
        .Application.Selection.EndKey Unit:=6 'wdStory
        .Application.Selection.TypeParagraph
        .Application.Selection.TypeParagraph
        .Application.Selection.Paste
        '.Application.Selection.TypeParagraph
        '.Application.Selection.TypeParagraph
    End With
    .htmlbody = .htmlbody & signature
    .Attachments.Add PDFFileName
End With
```

[Option 2]

```
' Include the content of the print area as a table in the email body
With OutMail
    .Display
    .To = "recipient@example.com" ' Replace with the recipient's email address
    .Subject = "Price Quotation"
    With .GetInspector.WordEditor
        .Application.Selection.HomeKey Unit:=6, Extend:=0 '6=wdStory; 0=wdMove
        .Application.Selection.TypeText "Dear recipient," & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Please find the price quote details below:"
        .Application.Selection.TypeParagraph
        .Application.Selection.TypeParagraph
        .Application.Selection.Paste
    End With
    .Attachments.Add PDFFileName
End With
```

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer! I have everything I need in my body now. However, I have another problem...
My automatic email signature shows up after "Dear recipient....." but before my pasting of the table. How can I place it in the end? Actually I don't need my "Best regards" text if I can just insert my mail signature. And I would also like to make sure the same font is used for the entire body...
I'm new in VBA so your help is much appreciated :)

Comment: I have edited my post, as per your request.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks so much Domenic! My body is now correct but I'm missing the email signature in the end...

Comment: When you referred to "My automatic email signature", I understood it to mean your default signature, which automatically appears when creating a new email.  If this is correct, the signature should appear at the end of the email message.

Comment: It is my default signature I'm missing. Is does not appear right now - everything else looks good. Sorry for being a little unclear.

Comment: I see the problem now.  The line getting the signature should be executed after the emails is displayed.  I have amended my post accordingly.

Comment: Also, since we're using the Word editor, we can avoid using the .HTMLBody property.  So I have also amended my post to include this other option.

Comment: I used option 2 and it works perfectly now, thanks so much for your help!